# C# Windows Forms Application error in browser while trying to load scripts

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019

Estoy intentando integrar un browser en un Windows Form vacio pero en algunas paginas me sale el siguiente error: "Error en el script de esta página" y la página se corrompe.
[image: 1]

El error es la imagen superior y la pagina corrupta es la imagen inferior. Supuestamente era www.g2a.com
[image: 2]
El proyecto ha sido configurado con la siguiente configuración: Visual Studio -> Aplicacion Windows Form (.NET Framework). Este es mi código y me ejecuta.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bot3._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.es");
        }
    }
}
```

PD: `ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` no me soluciona la página corrupta, simplemente que no me salte errores.

Comment: Alvaro este es un sitio en español como te habras dado cuenta al utilizarlo.

Comment: Perdona no me había percatado, ya lo he puesto en Español.